# Как решить проблему неопределенных переменных?

Tags: c, header

В моей программе есть переменные типа `uint8_t`, которые необходимо включить в директиву препроцессора для успешной компиляции моей программы. Как их включить? Включение `#include "cstdint.h"` дает ошибку. Мне хотелось бы взглянуть на cstdint.h. В чем различия `uint8_t` и `uint8_`?
Описание его читал здесь:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/

Comment: А можно немного понятнее? Как вы хотите (в идеале) включать переменные в директивы препроцессора?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего Вам необходимо подключить `#include <stdint.h>`.

`uint8_` больше походит на *промежуточное* определение типа `uint8_t` внутри какой-то **стандартной библиотеки C**, которую Вы используете. Вам про `uint8_` знать не надо.

Судя по Вашим другим вопросам, Вы стараетесь программировать микроконтроллер, но не имеете достаточный навык написания кода на языке C. Настоятельно рекомендую сначала изучить азы языка C, понять что такое компилятор и линковщик, что такое объектные файлы.

Рекомендую установить Visual Studio и попробовать написать пару простых сетевых приложений. Там же Вы легко сможете установить как определяется тип `uint8_t` в стандартной библиотеке C от MS. Так или иначе это будет `unsigned char`.